# 'ElasticProperty' could not be found in Nest 6.x

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

When trying to add an attribute 'ElasticProperty' i am getting the following error - 'ElasticProperty' could not be found.

```
[ElasticProperty(Analyzer = "some_string")]
public string Description { get; set; }
```

In one documentation I have read that 'ElasticProperty' is changed to 'String'. But even that is not working.

What should be the alternative for this?

Comment: `[String]` is an attribute in 2.x. in 5.x+, you should use `[Text]` or `[Keyword]` for analyzed and not_analyzed strings, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

using 'Text' worked for me.

```
[Text(Analyzer = "some_string")]
public string Description { get; set; }
```